# access a file in a volume named "home"

Tags: macos, file, applescript

My NAS has a shared point named "home" and is mounted in Os X (Big Sur)
This applescript reveals a bug. The System want it to be "/System/Volumes/Data/home" instead of "/Volumes/home/".

For test I wrote a text file named "dummy.txt" (with "hello world" inside) and run these lines :

```
get POSIX file "/Volumes/home/dummy.txt" -- returns the file object as follows
--> document file "dummy.txt" of disk "home" 
-- or --> file "home:dummy.txt"
-- or --> "file:///Volumes/home/dummy.txt"

do shell script "cat" & space & quoted form of "/Volumes/home/dummy.txt"
--> "hello world"

get file "home:dummy.txt"
--> ERROR

do shell script "cat" & space & quoted form of POSIX path of "home:dummy.txt"
--> ERROR : no such file or directory

get POSIX path of "home:dummy.txt"
--> "/System/Volumes/Data/home/dummy.txt"
```

Is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When coercing an HFS path to POSIX path the disk name `home` clashes with the invisible folder `home` on the top level of the startup disk.

To address the external volume use always the syntax

```
get POSIX file "/Volumes/home/dummy.txt"
```

and

```
do shell script "cat" & space & quoted form of "/Volumes/home/dummy.txt"
```

Comment: This is clear. I still can’t acces a file dropped using the « on open… » method : i got an aliases list.

Comment: An alias should point to the proper location. You can get the POSIX path directly from an alias. Just avoid an HFS path.